# How to print a the content of variables to tty?

Tags: kernel-module, tty

I am writing a kernel module, and would like to print to the terminal which ran the `insmod` instruction for debugging. I have found a few places where this is done like so
`((my_tty->driver)->ops->write) (my_tty, str, len)`, which works fine as long I have a constant string. But how can I do the same thing when I want to print a pointer and an integer ("%p %d")?

Code example:

```
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/slabh>
#include <linux/sched.h>
#include <linux/tty.h>

int init_module(void)
{
   int *n;
   struct tty_struct *tty;
   tty = current->signal->tty;
   (tty->driver)->ops->write (tty, "Hello\n", 6);  // What I know how to print to the terminal
   printk(KERNINFO "%p %d", n1, *n1);         // What I want to print to the terminal (not to the kernel ring buffer)
   return 0;
}

void cleanup_module(void)
{
   printk(KERN_INFO "Goodbye world.\n");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Build your string in a separate string with `sprintf`. The problem is when release the string memory. It may depends on the driver implementation. You can try with something simple like:

```
char str[32];
...
len = sprintf(str, "%p %p\n", n1, *n1);
(tty->driver)->ops->write (tty, str, len);
```

It is not the good thing to do but it gives you an idea of what you have to do.